# Any way to completely disable Windows Explorer, winlogon.exe, etc?

Tags: windows-10, command-line

I have changed the registry key to have my PC boot up into cmd instead of explorer.exe, but winlogon.exe still shows during logon and it's still possible to open Windows Explorer by typing explorer into the Command Prompt. Any way to completely disable explorer.exe and winlogon.exe and turn Windows 10 into a completely command line based OS?

Comment: How to get rid of explorer? Install MS-DOS. Okay, to be fair... I wonder if you know the true concequence of what you're suggesting. Explorer has many features that you may miss the moment you work with this. If you truly want to see what it will be like, I recommend you to install a VM, and install Windows Server 2012 or 2016 Core in it. It is exactly what you want, Windows with explorer disabled, but most essential features still working.

Comment: Here's a video of what Windows server 2012 R2 Core looks like and how to work with it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=djUWPvQAQZU

Comment: Also yes, Windows server core edition can be used as a workstation, and given that all the work has been done with it, if you really want this for your desktop, I would recommend installing this instead of Windows 10

Comment: Is it possible to install Windows Server Core Edition without removing local data?

Comment: @LPChip And I assume it is possible to install Windows Server Core Edition on a separate disk/partition?

Comment: Windows Server Core installs similarly to the desktop install that came out around the same time. Windows Server 2012 R2 installs like Windows 8.1, Windows Server 2016 installs like Windows 10. Both allow you to install it to separate disk/partitions, but as always, always make backups because it can go wrong if you are not paying attention, and then backups will allow you to recover.

Comment: My recommendation to install it to a VM first stands though. See if it really is what you want before committing to something like this.

Comment: @LPChip I now have 2 partitions on my main disk, a 1TB C: (Windows Client) and a 837GB S: (Windows Server). However, the installer only gives me the option of whether to keep personal data or not (the former of which is grayed out because it says that I can't keep personal data if it's a different edition of Windows), and it doesn't give me the option to select a partition.

Comment: Are you booting from the install medium, or are you running the setup.exe from within Windows? If you do the latter, it will attempt to perform an upgrade, that's not what you want. Booting from the install medium should give what you want.

Comment: @LPChip How would I boot from an "install medium"? I have tried using Rufus, but my computer does not support UEFI booting.

Comment: https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/ITProGuru/Create-Bootable-Windows-Server-2016-USB-Installation-Drive-Step-by-step

Comment: @LPChip I have actually used that exact guide before. Unfortunately however, it always corrupts my USB's file system no matter how mant times I try.

Comment: you may want to try a different USB drive. Sounds like your drive is having a problem.